# I'm trying to create a Filter in SparkAR with randon names cycling from an array

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I'm trying to create a Filter in SparkAR with random names cycling from an array on a 3D Text Layer

I made a node generating random number and sent to the script file to rool the names inside the array.

But the follow error return in the console for me:

```
Warning: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection:
 Error: valueOf() called on a Signal. This probably means that you are trying to perform an arithmetic operation on a signal like +, -, *, etc. Use functions .add, .sub(), etc on the signal instead or .subscribeWithSnapshot() on an EventSource to get the signal's current value on a callback.at anonymous
 (file:///polyfill.js:1:2983)at anonymous (file:///polyfill.js:1:1306)at anonymous (file:///polyfill.js:1:147)
```

i'm using this script:

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Patches = require('Patches');
const Reactive = require( 'Reactive');

export const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');


;(async function () {

  var randomNumber = await Patches.outputs.getScalar('randomNumberVar');
  var names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve"];
  var chosenName = names[randomNumber];

  await Patches.inputs.setString('chosenNameVar', chosenName);

})();
```

and this patch:

I just want make the names roll inside the effect in a 3D Text Layer

Can someone help me please